# Attribute package of manifest tag and R class problem

Tags: android, android-manifest

com.XXX.XXX is defined in androidManifest like this , package="com.XXX.XXX" . 
There are a few other packages in the project which are not defined in the manifest.

Except for the package defined in the manifest ( package="com.XXX.XXX" ) all other packages where resource are used have an error - R cannot be resolved to a variable.

I have checked and verified the following -

1. No java file has the import android.R or import com.XXX.XXX.R statements.
2. Deleted the R.java file under gen and regenerated it.
3. Refreshed the project and did a clean build.
4. Checked the layout .xml files for any errors , the console does not show any.

The project was working fine , I am not sure but I guess this error came after executing  layoutopt.bat under the tools directory.

Is there anything else that I can check to resolve this error.

Thanks,
Salil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a project-clean from the Project menu in Eclipse. And in any file that has errors do ctrl+o to fix the imports.

Comment: Robby,your solution works but I have read in many posts that com.XXX.XXX.R should not be imported manually. Is your solution better or the one given by Venkatesh ?

Comment: If you need to use it and it is in a different package then you will need to import it just like any other class.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your application's resources from another package via com.XXX.XXX.R.[...]